# Error in Compilation of Maven Project

Tags: maven, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to create an Maven Endpoint project and while creating i am getting the following statement in windows command prompt:

*Define value for property 'gcloud-version':  ${gcloud.plugin.version}: :*

Is there a specific version which i am supposed to enter?
When I tried giving default value, the project was created but later on when I tried compiling it, i got the following error in command prompt:

```
C:\projects\syncDb>mvn clean install        
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...    
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:    
 [ERROR] Resolving expression: '${gcloud.plugin.version}':  
 Detected the following recursive expression cycle in  'gcloud.plugin.version': [gcloud.plugin.version]    
 @[ERROR] Resolving expression: '${gcloud.plugin.version}': 
 Detected the followingrecursive expression cycle in 'gcloud.plugin.version': [gcloud.plugin.version]    
 @[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is '${gcloud.plugin.version}'. @ line 150, column 24    
 @[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]    
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR]   The project com.focusanything.syncDb:synchDb:1.0-SNAPSHOT(C:\projects\syncDb\pom.xml) has 3 errors    
 [ERROR]     Resolving expression: '${gcloud.plugin.version}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'gcloud.plugin.version': [gcloud.plugin.version] -> [Help 2]    
 [ERROR]     Resolving expression: '${gcloud.plugin.version}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'gcloud.plugin.version': [gcloud.plugin.version] -> [Help 2]    
 [ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is '${gcloud.plugin.version}'. @ line 150, column 24        
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the-eswitch.    
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

:

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. 
I took version from here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads 
and put it into pom.xml

`<gcloud.plugin.version>117</gcloud.plugin.version>`

Comment: how  you get to know which gcloud.plugin.version value you need to insert?

Answer (score 1):

The gcloud.plugin.version represents the version of the gcloud-maven-plugin you want to use. The list of versions can be found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/gcloud-maven-plugin

The present version is 2.0.9.133.v201611104 so the correct xml element to use in pom.xml is

```
<gcloud.plugin.version>2.0.9.133.v201611104</gcloud.plugin.version>
```